# ¿Cómo enviar valor incrementar-decrementar con ajax a php?

Tags: php, ajax

estoy intentando enviar el valor de un input text el cual se incrementa o decrementa con botones,
el problema viene al querer mandar ese valor po medio de ajax(jquery) les dejo el codigo..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
<meta name="viewport" content=" width=device-width, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1"/>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&family=Playfair+Display&display=swap" 
rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rajdhani:wght@400&display=swap" 
rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <header>
        <h1>Greacias por ordenar!</h1>
        <h4>Por fabor seleccione las unidades a encargar</h4>
    </header>
    
    <div class="container">
    
            <form method='post'>
    
                    <div class='val'>
                        <input type="button" onclick="decrementar()" value="-" class="dec"></input>
                        <input type='text' name="cantidad" value="0"  id='prod-cant'/>
                        <input type="button" onclick="incrementar()" value="+" class="inc"></input>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="contenedor-btn1">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn1" id="Enviar" onClick="enviar" name="Enviar" 
     value="Enviar Pedido">
                    </div>          
            </form>
</div>
```

y el codigo en js es el siguiente:

```
function incrementar() {
   var contador = $('#prod-cant').val();
if(contador < 10) {
    $('#prod-cant').val(parseInt(contador)+1);
}
 }
 function decrementar() {
var contador = $('#prod-cant').val();
if(contador > 1) {
    $('#prod-cant').val(parseInt(contador)-1);
}
```

}

```
 function enviar(){
var contador = $('#prod-cant').val();
$.ajax({
        type: "post", 
        url: "M33.php",
        data: {datos:contador},
        success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
                                }
    });
```

}

Actualmente no me muestra nada ni siquiera en consola, la idea es posteriormente concatenar ese dato con otro para luego guardarlos en un texto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para enviarlo por ajax:
tendrias que cambiar:

```
<form method='post'>
por:
<form method='post' onsubmit=" return false;">

<input type="submit" class="btn1" id="Enviar" onClick="enviar" name="Enviar" 
     value="Enviar Pedido">
por:
<input type="submit" class="btn1" id="Enviar"  name="Enviar" value="Enviar Pedido">


 function enviar(){
var contador = $('#prod-cant').val();
$.ajax({
        type: "post", 
        url: "M33.php",
        data: {datos:contador},
        success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
                                }
    });

}

por:


$(document).on('click','#Enviar', function (){
var contador = $('#prod-cant').val();
$.ajax({
        type: "post", 
        url: "M33.php",
        data: {datos:contador},
        success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
                                }
    });
    });
```

Comment: Genial! me sirvió de mucho.. gracias!